# IOS Push Notification Error with flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilhiu.png)

I am trying to add push notification with firebase to my flutter project. As a result of the request I made with Postman, I am getting NotRegistered error, and I am sharing my remaining codes. I would be very happy if you support me.

my main file;

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
await Firebase.initializeApp();
runApp(
child: const MyApp()),
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
Future<void> init() async {
await messaging.requestPermission(alert: true, announcement: false, badge: true, carPlay:          false, criticalAlert: false, provisional: false, sound: true);
final token = await messaging.getToken();
debugPrint(token);
await messaging.subscribeToTopic("topics-all");
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
(RemoteMessage message) {
  debugPrint('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    debugPrint('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
},
```

);
}
There is no problem on the Android part, but I have a problem with IOS. I made the necessary integrations on Firebase.

Comment: What version of `firebase_core` are you using? cause from your implementation it seems it's a very old one

Comment: firebase_core: ^2.8.0